# GDAL open error of NetCDF

Tags: python

I am running a Python script which converts .nc file to GeoTIFF, this script uses GDAL from Osgeo.

Following is the command I am giving Python:

```
from osgeo import gdal,osr, gdal_array
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np 


def GetnetCDFInfobyName(in_Sea_Surface_Temperature, var_name):

    # Function to read the original file's projection

    #Open netCDF File
    src_ds = gdal.open(in_Sea_Surface_Temperature)
    if src_ds is None:
        print (" Open Failed ")
        sys.exit()

    if src_ds.GetSubDatasets() > 1:
        subdataset = 'NETCDF:"'+ in_Sea_Surface_Temperature.nc +'":' + var_name

    # begin to read info of the named varaiable 

    NDV   = src_ds_sd.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()
    xsize = src_ds_sd.RasterXSize
    ysize = src_ds_sd.RasterYSize
    GeoT  = src_ds_sd.GetGeoTransform()
    Projection = osr.SpatialReference()
    Projection.ImportFromWkt(scr_ds.GetProjectionRef())

    # read data using array 

    xr_ensemble = xr.open_dataset(in_Sea_Surface_Temperature.nc)
    data = xr_ensemble[var_name]
    data = np.ma.masked_array(data, mask=data==NDV,fill_value=NDV)

    return NDV, xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection, data
def create_geotiff(suffix, Array, NDV, xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection):
    DataType = gdal_array.NumericTypeCodeToGDALToGDALTypecode(Array.dtype)

    if type(DataType)!=np.int:
        if DataType.startswith('gdal.GDT_')==False:
            DataType=eval('gdal.GDT_'+DataType)

    NewFileName = suffix +'.tif'
    zsize       = Array.shape[0]
    # create a driver 
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    # Set nans to the original No data value 
    Array[np.isnan(Array)] = NDV
    # Set up the dataset with zsize bands
    Dataset = driver.Create( NewFileName, xsize, ysize, zsize, DataType)
    Dataset.SetGeoTransform(GeoT)
    Dataset.SetProjection( Projection.ExportToWkt() )
    # Write each slice of the array along the size
    for i in xrange(0, zsize):
        DataSet.GetRasterBand(i+1).WriteArray( Array[i] )
        DataSet.GetRasterBand(i+1).SetNoDataValue(NDV)

    DataSet.FlushCache()
    return NewFileName
if __name__ == "__main__":
    infile   ='mslp.mon.mean'
    var_name ='mslp'
    NDV, xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection, data = GetnetCDFInfobyName(infile, var_name)
    outfile = create_geotiff(var_name, data, NDV, xsize, ysize, Geot, Projection)
    # plot the first frame
    import rasterio
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    src = rasterio.open(outfile)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    im =plt.imshow(src.read(1)/100.0, cmap='gist_rainbow')
    plt.title('Montly Sea Surface Temperature (°C) -Frame 1')

    from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
    divider = make_axes_locatable(plt.gcal())
    cax = divider.append_axes('right', '5%', pad='3%')
    plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

I'm getting the following error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-ba546bee5adf> in <module>
      2     infile   ='mslp.mon.mean.nc'
      3     var_name ='mslp'
----> 4     NDV, xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection, data = GetnetCDFInfobyName(infile, var_name)
      5     outfile = create_geotiff(var_name, data, NDV, xsize, ysize, Geot, Projection)
      6     # plot the first frame
<ipython-input-19-d9cca46bab20> in GetnetCDFInfobyName(in_Sea_Surface_Temperature, var_name)
      9 
     10     #Open netCDF File
---> 11     src_ds = gdal.open(in_Sea_Surface_Temperature.nc)
     12     if src_ds is None:
     13         print (" Open Failed ")
AttributeError: module 'osgeo.gdal' has no attribute 'open'
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Welcome indeed. Could you show us the code you have written so far?

Comment: It is Open -> `gdal.Open(in_Sea_Surface_Temperature.nc)`

Comment: This is the entire program .nc is providing error so plz resolve this issue

Comment: You may also be interested in rioxarray: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/convert_to_raster.html

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `rioxarray`
https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/convert_to_raster.html

```py
import rioxarray

infile = 'mslp.mon.mean'
var_name = 'mslp'
rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(infile, variable=var_name)
rds.rio.to_raster(f"{infile}_{var_name}.tif")
```